# How select min value in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table MS_FireStationOriginalMI data as:

```
 FireStation FireStationOriginalCode SortNo  Micode
    1                 1                  1    1
    1                 2                  1    2
    1                 3                  2    3
    1                 4                  1    2
```

Key: `FireStation FireStationOriginalCode` 
I write query as:

```
SELECT   Min(SortNo) as SortNo,m.FireStationOriginalCode
    FROM MS_FireStationOriginalMI m
    GROUP BY MICode
```

Result :

```
SortNo  FireStationOriginalCode
2          4
3          3
1          1
```

Why? `SortNo =2 but get FireStationOriginalCode=4`

I want `SortNo =2  and FireStationOriginalCode=2`

```
SortNo  FireStationOriginalCode
    2          2
    3          3
    1          1
```

How write sql?

Answer (score 1):

Your aggregate function, `MIN`, is in wrong column (and SQL engines other than SQLite will complaint about it)!

```
SELECT  SortNo, MIN(m.FireStationOriginalCode)
FROM MS_FireStationOriginalMI m
GROUP BY MICode;
```

will return desired result. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ad7e0/2)

EDIT: Your question wasn't clear to me, but know I think I understood:

```
SELECT o.SortNo, o.FireStationOriginalCode
FROM MS_FireStationOriginalMI o
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT  MICode, MIN(SortNo) AS SortNo
  FROM MS_FireStationOriginalMI m
  GROUP BY MICode
) AS m ON m.MICode=o.MICode AND m.SortNo=o.SortNo;
```

will return `(SortNo, FireStationOriginalCode)` matching minimum `SortNo` for each `MICode`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ad7e0/3)

Comment: I want get min SortNo

Comment: Can you support me, Case SortNo the same

Comment: How does `MICode` plays with this?

Comment: I can't understand what you want. I suggest you to edit your question and explicitly say what you pretend.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.a
     , x.b
     , x.c
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN (SELECT b,MIN(c) min_c FROM my_table GROUP BY b) y
    ON y.b = x.b
   AND y.min_c = x.c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   Min(SortNo) as SortNo,m.FireStationOriginalCode
    FROM MS_FireStationOriginalMI m
    GROUP BY m.FireStationOriginalCode
```

Comment: No,FireStationOriginalCode= 1,2,3,4, I want get row 1,2,3

Comment: @mum When you have an Aggregate function in the Select statement on one or more column, Any other column in the select statement thats not contained in any Aggregate function MUST go in `GROUP BY` Clause.

Comment: If GROUP BY m.FireStationOriginalCode will get 4 rows.

Comment: @mum Yep you should get four rows back, because you query says , get me all the `m.FireStationOriginalCode` and the minimum relevant `SortNo` for that `m.FireStationOriginalCode`. if you wan less rows use `WHERE` clause in you query to limit the number of rows returned

Answer (score 0):

I can get 3 rows first by sql:

```
SELECT m.*
  FROM MS_FireStationOriginalMI m
  Where m.FireStationOriginalCode=(Select b.FireStationOriginalCode from      MS_FireStationOriginalMI b where m.firestation = b.firestation and m.micode = b.micode  order by b.sortno limit 1)
```